# Why do we determine the values of λ in regularization as ln λ, such as ln λ=-18 instead of for example λ=0.3?

Tags: regularization

I'm studying Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Christopher Bishop. What I realized is, he defines values of λ as ln λ. For example:

> We see that, for a value of lnλ = −18, the over-fitting has been suppressed and we
>   now obtain a much closer representation of the underlying function sin(2πx). If,
>   however, we use too large a value for λ then we again obtain a poor fit, as shown in
>   Figure 1.7 for lnλ = 0

What is the reason for this? Why he doesn't just use λ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can just suppose, that it's because then we could consider regularization together with a Log Likelihood function, for instance, and that is why it's more convenient to have such a representation. It's easier to make computations, using log, for example, when we want to minimize some functions (ln a + ln b = ln(a*b), (ln a)' = 1/a etc)

Comment: I guess, that it's better for deeper understanding to watch on it in a context of other material such as a further implementation.